# live(), delegate(), and on() stop working after few ajax requests using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have html  elements with class "ajaxem" that are ment to be used in my jquery below. I also have the same for any form elements. For the first few ajax requests the jquery is attached and triggered and work properly. However, after a user logs in or registers, the returned links (which also have class="ajaxem") are not caught by jquery and not triggered.

I have tried all three implementations. and also tried to reapply them AFTER each ajax request. but none have worked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateajaxem() {


    $(document).on("click", "a.ajaxem", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var action = $(this).attr('href');
        //alert(action);
        if (action.indexOf('register') > 0) {

            $("div#logininfo").load("http://localhost/testrun/auth/register/").fadeIn();

        } else if (action.indexOf('password') > 0) {
            $("div#logininfo").load("http://localhost/testrun/auth/forgot_password/").fadeIn();

        }

    }); //end 
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 updateajaxem();

//$("a.ajaxem").live("click", function(e){ 

$(document).on("click", "input:submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var formaction = $(this).closest('form').attr('action');
    var dataString = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
    alert(dataString);
    //$("div#logininfo").load(formaction,data);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: formaction,
        data: dataString,
        //   dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);

            $("div#logininfo").html(data);
            updateajaxem();


        } // end of success
    });





});
</script>
```

the outputted html at which the scripts stop working is below:

```
<div id="container">
    <h1>Welcome to CodeIgniter!</h1>
<a href="auth/logout/">Logout</a> <a href="">Home</a>
    <div id="body">
        <p>The page you are looking at is being generated dynamically by CodeIgniter.</p>

        <p>If you would like to edit this page you'll find it located at:</p>
        <code>application/views/welcome_message.php</code>

        <p>The corresponding controller for this page is found at:</p>
        <code>application/controllers/welcome.php</code>

        <p>If you are exploring CodeIgniter for the very first time, you should start by reading the <a href="user_guide/">User Guide</a>.</p>
    </div>

    <p class="footer">Page rendered in <strong>1.0343</strong> seconds</p>
    <div id="logininfo">You have successfully registered. <a href="http://localhost/testrun/auth/login" class="ajaxem">Login</a></div>
</div>
```

which makes no sense since it includes the class "ajaxem" which should be caught by jquery but is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the returned link's `href` does not contain the words 'register' or 'password' neither of the following conditions are met:

```
if (action.indexOf('register') > 0) {
    $("div#logininfo").load("http://localhost/testrun/auth/register/").fadeIn();
} else if (action.indexOf('password') > 0) {
   $("div#logininfo").load("http://localhost/testrun/auth/forgot_password/").fadeIn();
}
```

so no ajax request happens.

You will probably need to account for the 'login' scenario, e.g.:

```
} else if (action.indexOf('login') > 0) {
   $("div#logininfo").load("http://localhost/testrun/auth/login/").fadeIn();
}
```

...and why hard-code the URLs when they can be extracted from the clicked anchor?

```
if (action.indexOf('register') > 0) {
    $("div#logininfo").load(this.href).fadeIn();
} else if (action.indexOf('password') > 0) {
   $("div#logininfo").load(this.href).fadeIn();
} else if (action.indexOf('login') > 0) {
   $("div#logininfo").load(this.href).fadeIn();
}
```

Comment: And you may now also notice a similarity in the branches of your final if/elseif statements... more refactoring ahead! ;-)

Comment: @Chris - Agreed. A switch/case perhaps or a regex.

Comment: I was actually thinking that the if statement is almsot superfluous given that all the branches do the same thing in your example code at least. It is of course doing nothing on the "else" but I'm not sure if just removing the whole `if` check in favour of just the `$("div#logininfo").load(this.href).fadeIn();` might not be better...